# What is the best way to synchronize tests in different packages which involve with a global variable?

Tags: testing, go, synchronization, mutex, parallel-testing

I'm working on a go project, my task is writing some tests for a package. The tests need to access a global variable in a different package. This global variable might be setup/access in different packages' testing. Because by default go testing runs in parallel for different packages. Therefore, setup/access to this variable might create race conditions.

The easiest way to synchronize is to create a shared **sync.Mutex** which spans in the different packages. Having said that, I tried to put this **sync.Mutex** in the xxx_test.go of xxx.go in which the global variable is declared, unfortunately, another package was not able to access this Mutex due to scope limitation. Eventually, I figured out I have to put this **sync.Mutex** to a utility package which is dedicated to testing, then different packages can access this Mutex to achieve sync purpose for that global variable.

I'm new to go lang. I just felt it's awkward that I need to create a utility package to just achieve sync purpose in the testing, on the other hand, if another developer does some testing in another package, he/she probably doesn't know where to find this **sync.Mutex**. Is there any better way to achieve this sync purpose with an elegant solution.

Many thanks!

Comment: That's one of the reasons why global variables aren't recommended... :)

Answer (score 2):

This question is impossibly broad. [Entire books](http://amzn.to/2fJWWcO) have been written on the topic.

But since you asked specifically about global variables, the simplest answer is:  Don't use global variables.

We're always taught that global variables are an anti-pattern. Testing is one of the main reasons that global variables and singletons is an anti-pattern.

If possible, refactor your global state to *at least allow* an instance variable, rather than a global.  Then you can pass that instance into your functions for testing.

As a simplified example, suppose you have the following global variable, and a function which uses it:

```
var globalFoo = 123

func doFoo() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("foo = %d", globalFoo)
}
```

Modify your function to take your variable as an argument:

```
func doFoo(foo int) string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("foo = %d", foo)
}
```

This can be more complicated if your global state is a database connection, or a large number of variables, but the principle is the same: Don't use globals; pass variables instead.

In a legacy codebase, one method to allow testing, without changing your function signatures, is to create simple wrapping functions:

```
func doFoo() string {
    return realDoFoo(globalFoo)
}

func realDoFoo(foo int) string {
    fmt.Sprintf("foo = %s", foo)
}
```